# How to change locale in angular 4

Tags: angular, internationalization

I have followed the tutorial of angular about i18n https://angular.io/guide/i18n , so i have created 2 files for ( messages.en.xlf and messages.fr.xlf ).

Whene i start my server like this `ng serve --aot --i18nFile=src/locale/messages.fr.xlf --i18nFormat=xlf --locale=fr` i see the right langue.  i have created 2 buttons for my 2 languages and i want to use a specific messages.xlf according to the click of the user. how can i do that ?

Answer (score 4):

you can configure angular i18n to get language from local storage, so you can add a function on click on languages buttons:

```
<button (click)='changeLang(lang)'></button>
```

and set localstorage in your ts and reload:

```
changeLang(lang: string) {
   localStorage.setItem('Language', lang);
   location.reload(true);
}
```

create a local folder next to your app forlder and put your translation files there, like messages.en.xlf , messages.fr.xlf ...

and don't add this in your providers inside app.module.ts

```
export function getCurentLocale(): string {
  return localStorage.getItem('Language') || 'en';
}


providers: [
  ...
{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: getCurentLocale() }
],
```

here is what should i18n-providers.ts look like

```
import { LOCALE_ID, TRANSLATIONS, TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT } from '@angular/core';

 export function getTranslationProviders(): Promise<Object[]> {
    let locale = 'en';
    if (localStorage.getItem('Language') !== undefined) {
     locale = localStorage.getItem('Language');
    }

  // return no providers if fail to get translation file for locale
  const noProviders: Object[] = [];

  // No locale or U.S. English: no translation providers
  if (!locale || locale === 'en') {
    return Promise.resolve(noProviders);
  }

 let translationFile = `./locale/messages.${locale}.xlf`;

 if (locale === 'en') {
    translationFile = './messages.xlf';
 }

  return loadTranslationFile(translationFile)
    .then( (translations: string ) => [
        { provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: translations },
        { provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, useValue: 'xlf' },
        { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: locale }
    ])
    .catch(() => noProviders); // ignore if file not found
   }

   function loadTranslationFile(file) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
       const   xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhr.open('GET', file, false);
       xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status === 0) {
                resolve(xhr.responseText);
            } else {
                reject({
                    status: xhr.status,
                    statusText: xhr.statusText
                });
            }
        } else {
            reject({
                status: xhr.status,
                statusText: xhr.statusText
            });                }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function () {
        reject({
            status: xhr.status,
            statusText: xhr.statusText
        });
    };
    xhr.send(null);
  });
   }
```

Comment: thank you for you answer. i understood the logic but since i am new in angular i don't know where to pu this code. is it in my app.component.ts ? or do i have to create a i18n-providers.ts file ?

Comment: if you don't have it, create it inside your app folder

Comment: Do I have to declare it or import it somewhere ? Or it 'll be done automatically?

Comment: you're welcome, i updated my answer, don't forgot  the config inside app.module.ts, check my update

Comment: Why did you not use httpClient instead of xhr?

Comment: which one is the fastest for the loading of the app ( httpClient  or xhr ) ?